# Angular 6 FormArray discard null fields

Tags: angular6, angular-formbuilder

I'm using `Angular 6`. I have a `FormArray` array like below

```
contactAddForm: FormGroup;
phone_numbers: FormArray;

ngOnInit() {

  this.contactAddForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    first_name: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ])
    phone_numbers: this.formBuilder.array([this.createPhoneNumberFormField()])
  });
}

createPhoneNumberFormField(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    phone: new FormControl(),
    primary: new FormControl()
  });
}
```

Here `phone` is **text** field while `primary` is **checkbox** which sends `true` or `false`.

But sometimes adding more fields dynamically and if submitted empty, the values assigned to `phone` and `primary` fields are **null**.

1. How can I discard formArray field with **null** `phone` field from submitting?
2. How to set `primary` default to **false** instead of **null**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default value to `FormControl` object, by providing it as the first parameter to its constructor.

```
createPhoneNumberFormField(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    phone: new FormControl(),
    primary: new FormControl(false) // asigning default as false
  });
}
```

If you want to remove the `null` fields before submitting them, then you will have to loop through `form controls` and remove them manually.